# Run tests with multiple dependency versions?

Tags: java, maven

My library depends on another library; let's call it "lib". I want to test my library with multiple versions of lib, in an automated manner.

1. Test if my library compiles for each version of lib.
2. Run JUnit 5 tests for each version of lib.

Are there any existing solutions for this?

I could write a script that changes the version number of lib in my `pom.xml` and executes `mvn compile` and `mvn surefire:test`. I could also use profiles and automate this with a script. I was hoping there is a better way, through something like a Maven plugin.

Comment: How many versions of lib are there?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Many. I want to test against multiple major/minor versions.

Comment: @Oliver You have not answered the question. Furthermore testing against an external lib is an integration test and should be handled by the failsafe plugin instead of surefire. You can create multiple modules which define different versions of the library and run integration tests against it... The other question is: Is that really necessary? The final question is: How many versions would you like to support?

Answer (score -1):

Maven focuses on reproducible builds which means that if you repeat the build at a later date you should get the same results which in turn requires that the dependency versions are fixed.

This fundamental mindset is what you want to challenge.  Maven won't like it even if it is for a good reason, and you will most likely need to have a separate full run for each version instead of looping inside Maven.

I was thinking that the way I would approach this, is to have a bill-of-materials POM that has a dependencyManagement section that lists the exact version you want to have, which is generated in the local filesystem before each run, and then orchestrate a run for each version you want to test.

You can also leverage your build system and have a repository which orchestrates this.  Github Actions can do array builds which might be what you need.

Comment: Downvoting? For pointing out that using an opinionated tool in a way it very much was not designed for. Oh well.